# How to retry all failed jobs from Redis queue in Laravel Horizon

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8, laravel-horizon

How can you retry **all** failed jobs in Laravel Horizon? There appears to be no "Retry All" button and the artisan command doesn't work as the failed jobs aren't stored in a table.

Answer (score 6):

The `queue:retry` command accepts `all` in place of an individual job ID:

```
php artisan queue:retry all
```

This will push all of the failed jobs back onto your redis queue for retry:

```
The failed job [44] has been pushed back onto the queue!
The failed job [43] has been pushed back onto the queue!
...
```

If you didn't create the failed logs table according to the installation guide with:

```
php artisan queue:failed-table
php artisan migrate
```

Then you may be up a creek. Maybe try interacting with redis manually and trying to access the list of failed jobs directly (assuming the failed jobs entries haven't been wiped - looks like they default to persisting in redis for a week, based on the config settings in `config/horizon.php`).

Answer (score 3):

> as the failed jobs aren't stored in a table

Actually, you should create that table. From the [Laravel Horizon documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/horizon#installation):

> You should also create the `failed_jobs` table which Laravel will use to
>   store any failed queue jobs:
>
> ```
> php artisan queue:failed-table
>
> php artisan migrate
> ```

Then, to [retry failed jobs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#dealing-with-failed-jobs):

> ### Retrying Failed Jobs
>
> To view all of your failed jobs that have been inserted into your
>   `failed_jobs` database table, you may use the `queue:failed` Artisan
>   command:
>
> ```
> php artisan queue:failed
> ```
>
> The `queue:failed` command will list the job ID, connection, queue,
>   and failure time. The job ID may be used to retry the failed job. For
>   instance, to retry a failed job that has an ID of 5, issue the
>   following command:
>
> ```
> php artisan queue:retry 5
> ```

Comment: This doesn't help me in the current situation as my failed queue is in Redis and those are the jobs that need retrying.